# Why Visual Studio 2019 format @if else in cshtml is so ugly?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, visual-studio-2019

When I try to format my code to make it look beautiful, this is what I expected.

```
@if (2 < 3)
{
     <h1>hello</h1>
}
else
{
     <h1>goodby</h1>
}
```

And this is two scenarios I get which is hella ugly.

```
    @if (2 < 3)
    {
<h1>hello</h1>}
    else
    {
 <h1>goodby</h1>}


    

     @if (2 < 3)
        {
    <h1>hello</h1>
}
        else
        {
     <h1>goodby</h1>
}
```

Why these kind of monstrosity formatting is a thing and how do I fix it?

Edit: I do not make ugly space distant when copy paste my code. That's literally how they look after I formated.

Edit 2: If anyone was wondering what my original code look like then here it is.

```
    <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="kt_datatable2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 25px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Đường thô nguyên liệu: activate to sort column descending">Đường thô nguyên liệu</th>
    @* UGLY!! *@
    @if (2 < 3)
    {
<th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="kt_datatable2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 64px;" aria-label="Ngày: activate to sort column ascending">Ngày</th> }
        else
        {
<th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="kt_datatable2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 64px;" aria-label="Giờ: activate to sort column ascending">Giờ</th>}
    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="kt_datatable2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;" aria-label="CaSx: activate to sort column ascending">CaSx</th>
    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="kt_datatable2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:  20px;" aria-label="Pol: activate to sort column ascending">Pol</th>
    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="kt_datatable2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;" aria-label="Độ ẩm: activate to sort column ascending">Độ ẩm</th>
    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="kt_datatable2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;" aria-label="Màu 2: activate to sort column ascending">Màu 2</th>
    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="kt_datatable2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;" aria-label="Tro sulfat: activate to sort column ascending">Tro sulfat</th>
    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="kt_datatable2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;" aria-label="Tro dẫn điện: activate to sort column ascending">Tro dẫn điện</th>
    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="kt_datatable2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;" aria-label="RS1: activate to sort column ascending">RS1</th>
    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="kt_datatable2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;" aria-label="RS2: activate to sort column ascending">RS2</th>
    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="kt_datatable2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;" aria-label="TKCT: activate to sort column ascending">TKCT</th>
    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="kt_datatable2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;" aria-label="Tinh bột (mg/kg): activate to sort column ascending">Tinh bột (mg/kg)</th>
    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="kt_datatable2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;" aria-label="Dextran (mg/kg): activate to sort column ascending">Dextran (mg/kg)</th>

    <th></th>
```

Comment: That's the command I use to format. These 2 ugly demon spawn is the result.

Comment: actually VS is still buggy in some rare scenarios of formatting. I personally don't care much about these kinds of bug.

Answer (score 0):

My best friends for this isse: **Ctrl + K**,  **Ctrl + D**

Comment: Yup. That the mother and father of these demon spawn. Sometime they format beautiful, somtime they give me these two abomination above.

Comment: you are right, sometimes I need to use **Ctrl + A** in advance to have it work :)